# How can I fix corner of storm door frame with clear view of outside?

Tags: storm-door

I had a contracting company from Home Depot install an Anderson storm door. When they initially installed it, I saw this hole in the corner of the storm door frame that you could see the outside from. I called them and they came out to "fix" it, and the guy said that's how it is supposed to be, and just stuffed styrofoam into the gap to "close off" the hole. I assume this is completely incorrect. How would I go about fixing this? I can add more pictures as needed, wasn't sure what would help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: An outside picture/s showing the hole section and above will help.  Most times would suggest you get them back to finish, but maybe that work is beyond what the job required.  Off hand without knowing enough, I think the door should have been placed closer to the wall, about an inch in more, so that gap is not there.

Comment: @crip659 added a photo showing the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a job for "door and window" spray foam. Caulk any gaps first so that you don't see the spray foam from the outside, then fill that void space with the foam. After it cures, trim off the excess or push it into the cavity and install trim on the inside

Comment: Any specific kind of trim? this is on the latch side so there isn't a ton of extra space with the handle.

Comment: @tallkid24, the particular trim is an aesthetic choice based on the geometry and other trim in the neighborhood of the door. If you're having trouble finding anything thin enough, check out PVC trim. It's tough and comes in lots of skinny shapes.